# Adding Reports To Managed Package Failing For Folder Already Exists?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package, dashboard, isv, reports-api

We have a managed packaged with reports and Dashboards in folders. If we add a report to an existing folder and deploy it to customers, the package install keeps failing with:

> "This folder unique name already exists for this folder type or has
>   been previously used."

This is suggesting that to add 1 report to a folder we'd have to delete the folder and all reports in customer org first, create a different folder name, and install that way? That cannot be the expected behavior. We also can't really do that because we have LEX components using some of those reports.

Comment: Is it possible to remove just the folder from the deployment?

Comment: Don't see how could do that. Upload is working and assume that uploading v2.0. For customers that don't have that version at all they would need the folder as part of package. On install it's a managed package so can't remove individual components.

Comment: Sure, was just curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the subfolder options in Lightning. You cannot package report subfolders in Lightning managed package right now. The initial install will work but upgrades will not. Appears related to this [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JWV5QAO) but slightly different. Found this out through trial and error.